# Deleting Table View Cell with Parse in Swift

Tags: swift, database, heroku, parse-platform

I have my app, which I have users which will post questions. I want the users to be able to delete their posts, which I sort of have been able to do. Here is my code.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        print("here1")
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.current())
        print("here2")
        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("THERE WAS AN ERROR DELETING THE OBJECT")
            }else{
                for object in objects!{
                    print("here3")
                    object.deleteInBackground()
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

As expected my code deleted all the posts from the current user. I don't know how to get just the selected post and delete only that one. 
Here is how the data base is structured

```
{
"_id": "EZY40tN2FR",
"location": [
    -122.0312186,
    37.33233141
],
"question": "Sldfksdlkfjsldfkjsldkfjsldkjf",
"category": "Entertainment",
"_p_user": "_User$R9GdCYnVno",
"_created_at": {
    "$date": "2017-10-17T01:03:11.438Z"
},
"_updated_at": {
    "$date": "2017-10-17T01:03:11.438Z"
}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Code for Getting Data:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery<PFObject> {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        query.includeKey("user")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.current()!)
        query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
        query.limit = 100
        return query
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your object to delete in this way:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        print("here1")
        let objectToDelete = objects?[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
        objectToDelete.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) in
            if (success) {
                // Force a reload of the table - fetching fresh data from Parse platform
                self.loadObjects()
            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the yourObjectsArray?

Comment: Hi @RohanRao, I suppose you are using the findObjectsInBackground query in a “loadData” function to populate your table view, update your question and show me how are you setting the table view datasource.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Im getting all the posts made by the user through a query. Could you look at my code and tell me where I could append all the PFObjects in to the array? I added the code to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RohanRao don’t worry ;) You’re using PFQueryTableViewController! I have edited my answer, try and let me know.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, when I changed the code, I got an error, Cannot convert value of type '(Bool, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type 'PFBooleanResultBlock?' (aka 'Optional<(Bool, Optional<Error>) -> ()>') It gives a fix but it doesn't really fix anything. How could I get rid of this error? Thanks

Comment: @RohanRao I have got the code from an old project and the deleteInBackground function probably is changed, I have edited my answer, I cannot try the code but if not works simply rewrite the method and it will give you the correct completion ;)

Comment: Hey thanks, I got it to delete from the parse database correctly, and reload thank you very much!